# Arshaw Calendar specific day css change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the color of the box in the month view in the arshaw calendar. This is what I have so far and I know I'm not great at javascript so I'm kinda stuck. What I should be able to do is the this script is called with the day to change the color. so first I save today's date, then I change the calender to the date they want. Then here I try to change the css of the calender, but it's not working :(. I then set back the date to original. All firebug is saying in console is undefined.

```
    function changeDate (dayToChange) {

    var original=$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',$('#calendar').fullCalendar.year,$('#calendar').fullCalendar.month, dayToChange );

    $($('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getDate' )).css('background-color', '#ffcccc');

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',original);
    var e = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getDate' );



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out myself :P

```
$('#calendar').find ('td.fc-day' + *dayToChange*).css('background-color', '#ffcccc');
```

This can be used in any javascript. You have to use the find jquery function because its level is way lower than `('#calender')` so you need it to search for all levels. The day to change will change the cell, NOT the actual day.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many duplicates of this questions already. Look at this for example:
[change the color of a cell in a full calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086360/change-the-color-of-a-cell-in-a-full-calendar/10114200#10114200)

Please do your research before posting questions here!

Comment: I already read that post, but i wasnt sure how to use that code either? is it possible for a full javascript solution in

  $(document).ready (function() 
  {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar
   ({
})
}
    
Thank you in advance :)